# How to edit a list of generated files whose names contain spaces

Tags: bash, command-line, xargs, vi

I've got a relatively small list of filenames generated from a pipeline based on `find`. The file names contain spaces and possibly punctuation but definitely no other non-printing characters or newlines.

For example,

```
Netherlands/Purge (GDPR) 2020-01-09.txt
Netherlands/Purge (GDPR) 2020-01-27.txt
Switzerland/New mailing 2020-01-27.txt
```

I want to edit these files as a set (`vi file1 file2 file3` rather than `vi file1; vi file2; vi file3`), partly so that I can easily jump forwards and backwards between them.

I've started with [Using a generated list of filenames as argument list — with spaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110068/100397)
, which has a standard `find -print0 | xargs -0 mycommand` solution. Unfortunately this does not work when `mycommand` is an editor because although `xargs` can assemble the set of files to edit, *stdin* is already taken up from the pipeline and I can't see a way to run an editor in-place. I can't use `find -exec vi {} +` because I'm using a pipeline to validate the set of filenames, and not just `find` itself.

My other option is to copy and paste, assembling the list of file names, surrounding them with quotes, and then prefixing the result with `vi`. For these three files it's trivial, but in the general case it's not an easily-reusable solution,

```
vi 'Netherlands/Purge (GDPR) 2020-01-09.txt' 'Netherlands/Purge (GDPR) 2020-01-27.txt' 'Switzerland/New mailing 2020-01-27.txt'
```

Given a GNU/Linux platform with `bash` as my preferred shell (in case it matters), how can I edit a similarly generated list of files?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on the pipeline and that filename validation part ? Can't you do `find | something | xargs vi` with something like `find -exec something -exec vi` ?

Comment: @pLumo I'm hesitant to scar you with the entire pipeline, but it's along the lines of `find -type f -mtime +14 -mtime -22 -iname '*.xml' | while IFS= read -f x; do xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v '//magicElement -n "$x" | grep -q magicValue && echo "$x"; done`

Comment: thanks, it does not scare me at all. :-D

Comment: You could use the quickfix list as a workaround: vi -q (if yours supports it)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm not familiar with that; would you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comments I get something similar like this is your command:

```
find -type f -mtime +14 -mtime -22 -iname '*.xml' | while IFS= read -f x; do xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v '//magicElement' -n "$x" | grep -q magicValue && echo "$x"; done
```

Instead of piping to a `while` - loop you could use `-exec sh -c '...'` to filter files:

```
find -type f -mtime +14 -mtime -22 -iname '*.xml' \
  -exec sh -c 'xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v "//magicElement" "$1" | grep -q magicValue' find-sh {} \; \
  -exec vi -- {} +
```

---

Try:

Consider three files:

```
.
├── a:<magicElement>magicValue</magicElement>
├── b:<magicElement>magicValue</magicElement>
└── c:<magicElement>someOtherValue</magicElement>

$ find . -type f \
  -exec sh -c 'xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v "//magicElement" "$1" | grep -q magicValue' find-sh {} \; \
  -exec echo vi -- {} +
```

Output:

```
vi -- ./a ./b
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you are in Bash,

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -d '' -t files < <(find path -type f -print0)
vi -- "${files[@]}"
```

Replace `find path -type f -print0` with your actual pipeline.

Although your files have no newlines, the support for such filenames has been added by user *glenn jackman*.

To use tabs instead of buffers for `vi`, add the `-p` flag: `vi -p ...`.

---

If the pipeline was not required, you could straighforwardly use the `-exec` option:

```
find path -type f -exec vi -- {} +
```

Comment: That's almost perfect. Unfortunately my filenames are generated from a pipeline not just from `find`. I've made that statement in the question stronger

Comment: @Quasímodo, or, without the loop `readarray -t files < <(find ...)`

Comment: I did update the readarray command for newline safety, as it was not an intrusive change.

Comment: You can also use `read -d ''` with `find -print0`, but really `readarray` is the way to populate an array

Answer (score 7):

> *Unfortunately this does not work when mycommand is an editor because although xargs can assemble the set of files to edit, stdin is already taken up from the pipeline and I can't see a way to run an editor in-place.*

That way is documented in the manual page for the GNU Findutils `xargs`:

```
   -o, --open-tty
          Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process  before  executing
          the  command.  This is useful if you want xargs to run an inter‐
          active application.
```

So that you could use

```
find . -name 'pattern' -print0 | xargs -0o vim
```

However, it is a newer feature. I don't see it in an older system that has xargs 4.4.2; I see it on Ubuntu 18, which has xargs 4.7.0.

Now `xargs` may not have had the `-o` option ten years ago, but Bash process substitution existed ten years ago, and `xargs` has the `-a` option to read from a file instead of standard input.

So the problem is solvable without `xargs -o` like this:

```
xargs -0 -a <(find . -name 'pattern' -print0) vim
```

Because `xargs` is reading from (what it thinks is) a file that it received as an argument, it has left standard input alone.

Comment: +1. Even if process substitution is unavailable, one may resort to intermediary files, named FIFOs, or stream redirection plus `/dev/fd/*`. Another alternative is to add a wrapper around `vim` that reopens the TTY on stdin: `find […] | xargs […] sh -c 'exec vim "$@" < "\`tty\`"'` _

Answer (score 1):

If your vi supports it (and, if your vi is vim, it does), you could use the quickfix list. This is a feature that stores file-names<sup>1</sup> in a navigable list. The important commands are `:cnext` and `:cprev`, the equivalent of `:next` and `:prev` for quickfix entries. Many others, like `:cfile`, `:cfirst`, `:clast`, and `:copen`, also exist.

So, the question becomes, how to load the files into the quickfix list? Here are some options:

1. Put the filenames into some kind of file, and use `vi -q <file>`: the quickfix list will be set based on the file. But if you try this where file contains, e.g.,

```
Netherlands/Purge (GDPR) 2020-01-09.txt
Netherlands/Purge (GDPR) 2020-01-27.txt
Switzerland/New mailing 2020-01-27.txt
```

You will be disappointed. The default `'errorformat'`, which tells vi how to parse file-names out of the error messages, is set for C compilers. So you will need

```
vi --cmd 'set errorformat=%f' -q <file>
```

There are several ways to create `<file>`; one is `pipeline ... >errors`. But then you have to delete the file.

More interesting, if your shell supports it, is

```
vi --cmd 'set errorformat=%f' -q <(pipeline)
```

2. Use the `:cexpr` command with the `system()` function: load up vi and run the commands

```
set errorformat=%f
cexpr system('pipeline')
```

This is similar to the command line version, but involves an extra step and a more advanced command. This is more useful if you're already in vi when you need to set the quickfix list (though at this point I might just do

```
:args `pipeline`
```

assuming that didn't break on spaces and I didn't care about the current argument list).

#### Notes

1. Often, the file-names are combined with line or column numbers and sometimes even messages—such as from a compiler. `:help quickfix` for more.
2. If you do this sort of thing a lot, you may like this shell function:

```
vq () {
  if (($# > 0)); then
    vim -q <("$@" 2>&1)
  else
    printf '%s\n' 'Usage: vq cmd' '' 'Use {cmd} output as quickfix list'
  fi
}
```

You provide a single command (often `grep` or the like) to `vq` and it does the rest; but it only works if the commands output fits into the default `'errorformat'`. Adjusting `'errorformat'` after the quickfix list is loaded should work, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ugly hacks I have used for years for this problem. both require X.

```
find ... -print0| ...| xargs -0r gvim -f

find ... -print0| ...| xargs -0r xterm -e vim
```

It works, even over ssh.

Comment: Very clever, I'll try to remember this for future use